# Google Maps URL can't be Opened in App

Tags: android, html, google-maps

So I wrote some code to link directions to a destination using the correctly formatted address found with the Google API. This link works correctly in the Chrome browser but is seen as an Unsupported Link in the Google Maps Application on phones.

Here is the link:

```
<a target="_blank" href="https://www.google.com/maps?saddr=My+Location&daddr=<?php echo urlencode($listing[$i]['address']); ?>">rental location</a>
```

Comment: what are you trying to do?? can you be precise on what is your issue here?

Comment: I'm trying to provide a URL for Google maps directions to an address, it works when the link is opened in the browser but not when it's opened in the Google maps application.

Comment: "opened in the Google maps application" how are you doing this? also does ur url have php blah blah when passing data to maps??

Comment: I am doing this on an android. What do you mean php blah blah? The end result of the link would look something like this: https://www.google.com/maps?saddr=My+Location&daddr=Indianapolis+Indiana+United+States

Comment: i meant <?php echo urlencode($listing[$i]['address']); ?> that you have defined

Comment: can you paste the code for how you are invoking google maps in ur app

Comment: Just look at it like this, forget the code. The link is this: https://www.google.com/maps?saddr=My+Location&daddr=1000+N+New+York+Ave%2C+Muncie%2C+IN+47303%2C+USA
It won't open correctly in Google Maps Application on phones but it will in browsers.